# How to set additivity to false when the Appender is added programatically

Tags: log4j

I am new to log4j. My requirement is to create a new log file during every iteration. Basically during every iteration, below is what I need to attain:

1. Create a folder with current timestamp as the folder's name
2. Create a log file with name log.txt
3. Log the transactions of that iteration in log.txt

I have given a mock up of the implementation i need.

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO

log4j.appender.tracerLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.tracerLog.File=logs/${log4j.test.start.timestamp}/tracer.log
log4j.appender.tracerLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.tracerLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p - %m%n

log4j.category.traceLogger=TRACE, tracerLog
log4j.additivity.traceLogger=false
```

java code

```
package app.testscript;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;

public class Log4jTest {
    static{
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hh_mm_ss_S");
        System.setProperty("log4j.test.start.timestamp", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
    Logger traceLogger = Logger.getLogger("traceLogger");
    Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();

    Logger testScriptLogger = null;

    public void doSomething() {

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hh_mm_ss_S");
            PatternLayout patterLayout = new PatternLayout("%m%n");
            String folderNameToCreate = dateFormat.format(new Date());

            FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender(patterLayout, "C:/MyTestLog/" + folderNameToCreate + "/log.txt", true);
            fileAppender.setName("A" + folderNameToCreate);
            fileAppender.activateOptions();
            rootLogger.addAppender(fileAppender);           

            try {
                testScriptLogger = LogManager.getLogger("A" + folderNameToCreate);
            }catch(Exception e1) {
                System.out.println("Exception e: ");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            //testScriptLogger.setAdditivity(false);
            testScriptLogger.info("Message to capture in log - " + folderNameToCreate);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Log4jTest obj = new Log4jTest();
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            obj.doSomething();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Result of the above Code**:

1. I can see there are 2 folders created (folder_1 and folder_2)
2. Both the folders have the log.txt in it
3. log.txt file created (inside folder_1) during iteration 1 have 2 lines in it (log related to iteration 1 and iteration 2)
4. log.txt file created (inside folder_2) during iteration 2 have one line it (log related to iteration 2)

[image]

**Expected Result** is to have 1 line in both the log.txt files (created during iteration 1 and 2)

[image]

When using `testScriptLogger.setAdditivity(false);` , I get the below WARNING message and nothing is written to the file.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (A20170518_03_49_10_802).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Please help me with a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Java code:

```
package app.testscript;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;

public class Log4jTest {
    static{
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hh_mm_ss_S");
        System.setProperty("log4j.test.start.timestamp", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
    Logger scriptLogger = Logger.getLogger("scriptLogger");
    String prevAppenderName = "";

    public void removeBaseAppenderConfiguredInlog4jProperties() {
        scriptLogger.removeAppender("scriptLog");
    }

    public void doSomething() {

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hh_mm_ss_S");
            PatternLayout patterLayout = new PatternLayout("%m%n");
            String folderNameToCreate = dateFormat.format(new Date());

            FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender(patterLayout, "C:/MyTestLog/" + folderNameToCreate + "/log.txt", true);
            fileAppender.setName("A" + folderNameToCreate);
            fileAppender.activateOptions();

            if(!prevAppenderName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                scriptLogger.removeAppender(prevAppenderName);
            }           

            scriptLogger.addAppender(fileAppender);         
            prevAppenderName="A" + folderNameToCreate;

            scriptLogger.setAdditivity(false);
            scriptLogger.info("Message to capture in log - " + folderNameToCreate);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Log4jTest obj = new Log4jTest();
        obj.removeBaseAppenderConfiguredInlog4jProperties();
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            obj.doSomething();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```